# How to 'label' module using electric techniques

Tags: arduino-mega, resistor

I am in a project where it makes set of 'modules(set of separate circuits that will work as a sensor when connected to the board' that would be connected to Arduino Mega.

Currently, I'm planning to connect 'modules' with the Mega board using RJ-45(also known as LAN cable) cables.

At first, using voltage divider circuit, I tried to identify these 'modules' by attaching a resistor to it, so that if the board sends 5V to the 'module', it gets the resistance of the resistor inside the module.

But, as soon as I tested, this way seemed a bit unstable, because the measured resistance of the resistor kept changing.

Now, is there any other way to 'label' the module? I'm a beginner in this thing, so I'll appreciate any help that is provided.

Thanks in advance.

Ps. the voltage divider circuit that I used can be found in here:

Ps2. the resistor in the module does not mean the total resistance of the circuit in the module. It's separate.

Comment: What kind of sensors / communication protocol / electrical signalling are you using?

Comment: each modules have sensors like photo-interrupter in it, and through the RJ-45, are provided VCC,GND, 2 digital inputs, 2 analog inputs, a PWM, and 1 pin is left for the identification.

Comment: That starts getting kind of tricky then...  Let me put my thinking cap on for a while...

Comment: `the voltage divider circuit that I used can be found in here:`; no link present. Raspberry hats use I2C EEPROM to identify the 'HAT'/shield. I've seen people using a DS18S20 temperature sensor, as those also include a 64-bit unique identifier. Though both of these will a relatively expensive options. It could be the long lengths of cable that mess with the resistance. So maybe you could add a constant current source on the modules; then add a 'terminating' resistor at the Arduino, and measure the voltage across it.

Comment: Personally I would have made the modules purely digital. Add a small microcontroller to each one to interact directly with the sensor in the module, and then use a digital protocol (RS-485, RS-422, LVDS, etc) to communicate between the module and the main board. That way the protocol can include a "tell me what you are" request. Cable length then also doesn't affect analog readings.

Comment: It also means the sensor modules themselves then contain the code needed to interact with the sensor. The main board doesn't need to know how to do that - only how to request data from it, or send settings to it.

Comment: You still haven't provided the divider circuit!!!

Comment: @Gerben Gosh... my eyes are dim lately... here's the link: http://www.circuitbasics.com/arduino-ohm-meter/

Comment: What kind of values are you using? You might want to try adding a small capacitor near the analog pin on the arduino to stabilize the voltage. PS maybe your eyes need an op-amp (optical amplifier) q-;

Comment: @Gerben Pardon me, I didn't get the 'What kind of values are you using?'...

Comment: Resistor values in ohms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable / unwilling to change your interface into a purely digital system whereby a small microcontroller in the sensor module interfaces the sensor with a communication bus, the best method is probably to include a small 1-wire EEPROM with each module.

An ideal one would be the [DS2431](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/digital/memory-products/DS2431.html) which provides 1024 bits (128 bytes) of EEPROM storage using just 1 wire to both communicate and provide power.

Programming in a unique identifier for the module would be a simple enough task, and that unique ID can then be used to work out what the module is.

The DS2431 is pretty cheap too, available at prices around  $1.50 and below (much less for bulk and surface mount).

You can also get bigger versions for storing more data should you want to.

Comment: humm... if the digital storage is the only answer... then I shall follow. Thanks so much!